# Identify "$" that is immediately followed by only alphabet/alphanumeric words

Tags: bash, shell

"$" should not be immediately followed by digits [0-9]. It should only show the 
output- "$" which is immediately followed by aphabet/alphanumeric/alphacharacter.

Input: `dirname $0/../bin/$12JAVA_INV/$FILE12NAME`

Output: `$FILE12NAME`

```
grep -o '[$][a-zA-z_]*'
```

Using this I'm receiving an output as: `$ $ $FILENAME`

Comment: @Cyrus I agree with you on this and I've shared some part of the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `$` in the result because `*` means to match *zero* or more of the preceding pattern. `$0` matches because it has a `$` followed by 0 letters.
If you want at least 1 letter, use `+` instead, it means *one* or more.

But if you want to be able to match `$FILE12NAME`, you also need to allow digits after the first character. So use:

```
grep -i -o '\$[a-z_][a-z_0-9]*'
```

This matches `$`, followed by a letter or underscore, followed by zero or more letters, underscores, or numbers.

Comment: Better: `'\$[[:alpha:]_][:alnum:]_]` (`-i` isn't needed and it works in any locale).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
$ echo 'dirname $0/../bin/$12JAVA_INV/$FILE12NAME' | awk '{print $NF}' FS=/
$FILE12NAME
```

But if you really want to parse it the way you describe, you could do either of:

```
$ echo 'dirname $0/../bin/$12JAVA_INV/$FILE12NAME' | sed -e 's/.*\(\$[^0-9]\)/\1/'
$FILE12NAME
$ echo 'dirname $0/../bin/$12JAVA_INV/$FILE12NAME' | sed -E 's/.*(\$[^0-9])/\1/'
$FILE12NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please describe it a little?